# mockMvc assert that content is null (content is not json)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, mockmvc

I want to assert that the returned content (model and view) are both null on certain conditions but I can't find the right Matcher. Could someone please show me how this should be done? If this problem was solved in another thread I apologize I could not find it.

```java
mockMvc.perform(get("/test")
    .headers(assembleBasicAuthHeader("idontexist", "gibberish")))
    .andExpect(status().isForbidden())
    .andExpect(content().isNull()) //this obviously doesnt work 
            .andExpect(model().isNull()) //this obviously doesnt work 
    .andExpect(status().reason(containsString("Forbidden")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your API supports JSON (it's not clear from your question), one way would be to assert the response body using JSON path expressions:

```
mockMvc.perform(get(..)
        .headers(..)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isForbidden())
    .andExpect(status().reason(..))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$").doesNotExist());
```

Comment: I have found this option but this does only guarantees there's no jsonbody. In another test where there is actually a body (but not JSON) this test ( falsely ) passes.

Comment: Right, I assumed that your API supports only JSON. I updated my response accordingly. OTOH, you should probably have separate tests for scenarios when a response body is expected regardless of the media type returned.

Comment: Another suggestion would be that HTTP-403 should always return a response body, one that preferably matches the single format of any other error responses from your API. Only HTTP-204 should return no response body.